# structure within union showing warning and some unpredictible output

Tags: c

```
    #include<stdio.h> 
    typedef union 
    {
           struct accname
           {
                   char sbi[20];
                   char canara[20];
                   char hdfc[20];
                   char icici[20];
           }; 
    } unionv; 

    void main()  
    {
           unionv var1;
           struct accname var2;
           printf("sizeof union=%d\n",sizeof(var1));
           printf("sizeof str=%d\n",sizeof(var2));
    }
```

Here it is showing warning.

```
warning: declaration does not declare anything [enabled by default]  }unionv
```

Can anybody clear why it is showing warning?

Comment: Why would you declare a union with only one member?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html#Unnamed-Fields

The unnamed field must be a `structure` or `union` definition without a tag, for example,

```
typedef union 
{
     struct accname
     {
        //member      
     }; // without tag
} unionv;
```

If `-fms-extensions` is used, the field may also be a definition with a `tag` such as `struct foo { int a; };`, a reference to a previously defined `structure` or `union` such as `struct foo`;, or a reference to a `typedef` name for a previously defined `structure` or `union` type.